# Reverse order in partitions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, partitioning

I have this query

```
select
*,
row_number() over w,
sum(satisfied::integer) over w,
round(avg(satisfied::integer) over w, 3)*10
from compositions_rating
window w as (partition by user_id order by rating_date asc)
```

That gives me this (took part of partitions where user_id = 1)[image: partition]

But also I want to have make query with reversed order in partition like this [image: partition 2]

May be this is silly question, but how can I do this?

UPD:
My best attempt was this

```
select
*,
row_number() over w,
sum(satisfied::integer) over w,
round(avg(satisfied::integer) over w, 3)*10
from compositions_rating
window w as (partition by user_id order by rating_date desc rows between current row and UNBOUNDED following)
```

But row numbers are going in normal order in this case, as they were supposed to[image]

UPD2:
What you get if ordering after partitions made
[image: order]

Comment: Adding a final `order by rating_date desc`?

Comment: I misread a bit your message, then everything is messed up completely (partitions are ruined after)

Comment: Should be `order by user_id, rating_date desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like you already have the expected result but simply want to change the complete order afterwards... So, doesn't this solve you problem?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
   -- <your query>
) s
ORDER BY user_id, rating_date DESC
```

Comment: Doing something like this ruining partitions and all rows are just ordered by rating_date. I will add screenshot to my post

Comment: @wmdanor this ORDER BY clause is placed at the end of your query and not inside OVER clauses and it does not affect the partitions. It affects the order of the rows that you get.

Comment: Hi, it would be much more helpful to see some real copy-able sample data. Best would be to create a fiddle like here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f1c6e9b131285f307923951ba827e56f

Comment: @S-Man in process of doing this

Comment: @forpas what I meant that rows that were partitioned within same user_id and ordered in this partitions by date became ordered simply by date

Comment: @S-Man here is 200 first rows from my table, i can bring more if you want https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d58e21d29ae556977741a4baef8dd881

Comment: Simply add `user_id` to the final ORDER BY

Comment: Added the user_id as @dnoeth mentioned. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6d452aba0804fa0c62341b3342cfb39d

Comment: @S-Man thank you very much, I've came up with same solution the same second you posted your answer. I don't know why I was so stuck on this.